# Add static lib .lib and .a file in android studio

Tags: c++, cmake, android-ndk

I'm trying to add .lib file and .a (x64) file to Android project with a native component but I got an error in CMakelists.txt
error:

```
CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "LIB".
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: LIB
-- Generating done
CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
```

my following CMakelists like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(testGu)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
include_directories(GuruX)
link_directories(GuruX/include)
add_library(guruxLib STATIC IMPORTED  )
add_executable(testGu  main.cpp)
set_target_properties(libGuruX PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION  D:\\testGu\\GuruX\\lib\\libGuruX.a)
add_library(LIB GuruX/lib/GuruxDLMS)
target_link_libraries(LIB SHARED GuruX/lib/GuruxDLMS)
```

where

```
|-GuruX 
     |-lib
        |-libGuruX.a
        |-GuruxDLMS.lib
     |-includes (*.h files)
```

Comment: By "my android studio" you mean an Android project with a native component? For which architecture was `libGuruX.a` compiled? That must match the target device.

Comment: yeah, my android studio means Android project with a native component

Comment: Okay, how and for which architecture did you compile `libGuruX.a`?

Comment: using ubuntu command
$ readelf -h libGuruX.a | grep 'Class\|File\|Machine'
File: libGuruX.a(*.o)
  Class:                             ELF32
  Machine:                           Intel 80386

Comment: OS/ABI: UNIX -System V

Comment: "... but I got an error in CMakelists.txt" - Please, [edit] the question post and add that error message into it. See also [ask].

Comment: @MohammedHassan you cannot use that library for most Android devices. They use ARM or ARM64 and you're trying to link a library for x86.